# Bottom Navigation Activity shows unexpected margin on top of fragments

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, margin

I'm in the process of adding a bottom navigation bar to my app.

I used the code in the "Bottom Navigation Activity" sample project you get from Android Studio as a reference. "New Project - Bottom Navigation Activity".

It all work ok, except I get an unexpected margin area between the fragments and the action toolbar.

First I thought I must have made a mistake when "mirroring" the sample project. Then I checked the sample project itself (the unmodified code I get from Android Studio) and it turns out the margin is there too out of the box!

See the screenshot, I changed the fragment's background color so that to make the margin visible.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: can you share your activity.xml?

Comment: It's the default code you get when creating a new "Bottom Navigation Activity" project in Android Studio. It's ok now, it turns out I missed that "paddingTop" property in the main activity's top layout. Why would Android Studio add that line? Go figure. Thanks for reacting so fast, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it the main activity's layout file contains this line in the top layout ...

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

... which needs to be removed. After that the margin is gone.